# marklogic installation fails on Rocky Linux 8 or 9

Tags: linux, windows-subsystem-for-linux, marklogic-10, rocky-os

I've installed Rocky Linux 8 on WSL and then installed MarkLogic 10 on it. However, when I attempt to start the MarkLogic service using the command:

```
sudo systemctl start MarkLogic.service
```

I encounter the following error:

```
Job for MarkLogic.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status MarkLogic.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

When I check the status of the service using systemctl status MarkLogic.service, I receive the following output:

```
MarkLogic.service - LSB: MarkLogic Server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/rc.d/init.d/MarkLogic; generated)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2023-08-24 19:39:41 IST; 16s ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 200 ExecStart=/etc/rc.d/init.d/MarkLogic start (code=exited, status=127)

Aug 24 19:39:38 IN-F6KRXM3 systemd[1]: Starting LSB: MarkLogic Server...
Aug 24 19:39:38 IN-F6KRXM3 MarkLogic[201]: Initializing environment variables
Aug 24 19:39:40 IN-F6KRXM3 MarkLogic[200]: Starting MarkLogic:
Aug 24 19:39:40 IN-F6KRXM3 MarkLogic[205]: /etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_start_daemon: line 3: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file
Aug 24 19:39:40 IN-F6KRXM3 MarkLogic[206]: /etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_start_daemon: line 44: daemon: command not found
Aug 24 19:39:41 IN-F6KRXM3 MarkLogic[207]: /etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_log_message: line 3: /etc/init.d/functions: No such file
Aug 24 19:39:41 IN-F6KRXM3 MarkLogic[208]: /etc/redhat-lsb/lsb_log_message: line 16: failure: command not found
Aug 24 19:39:41 IN-F6KRXM3 systemd[1]: MarkLogic.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=127
Aug 24 19:39:41 IN-F6KRXM3 systemd[1]: MarkLogic.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Aug 24 19:39:41 IN-F6KRXM3 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: MarkLogic Server.
```

I would appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that MarkLogic might be incompatible with your version of Linux.  Some Linux distros use `/etc/init.d` and some don't.   For instance Ubuntu uses `/lib/lsb/init-functions`.  I would make sure that the version of MarkLogic you are using is compatible with your distro ..

Comment: Also I know this goes without saying .. But ensure you actually have `redhat-lsb-core` installed.

Comment: Hi Zak, thank you for the response, It got resolved by installing init scripts with the following command "sudo yum install initscripts"